# NullPointerException onPostExecute in Asynctask

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have added icon in menu toolbar which when pressed rotates for some seconds executes the code which check if any updates are availaible or not for app and then animation stops.
It well worked before but I don't know from today morning it check the updates but then instead of stopping animation , the app crashes with below logcat.

```
 Process: com.nepalpolice.yummyfood, PID: 3400
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nepalpolice.yummyfood.MainActivity.resetUpdating(MainActivity.java:248)
    at com.nepalpolice.yummyfood.update.UpdateTask.onPostExecute(UpdateTask.java:37)
    at com.nepalpolice.yummyfood.update.UpdateTask.onPostExecute(UpdateTask.java:12)
```

Below is resetUpdating method from Mainactivity

```
   public void resetUpdating() {
    // Get our refresh item from the menu
    MenuItem m = mymenu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        if (m.getActionView() != null) {
            // Remove the animation.
            m.getActionView().clearAnimation();
            m.setActionView(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Updatetask Class

```
public class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
private Context mCon;

public UpdateTask(Context con)
{
    mCon = con;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... nope) {
    try {
        // Set a time to simulate a long update process.
        Thread.sleep(4000);

        return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void nope) {

    ((MainActivity) mCon).resetUpdating();

       }
    }
```

UpdateSErvice Class

```
    public class UpdateService extends Service {          
    public UpdateService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    String url = "http://updatesagar.blogspot.com/2018/06/msc.html";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            if(response != null ) {
                boolean resp = response.contains("<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-4386558807662471459' itemprop='description articleBody'>\n" +
                        "<div dir=\"ltr\" style=\"text-align: left;\" trbidi=\"on\">\n" +
                        "11</div>\n" +
                        "<div style='clear: both;'></div>");

                if (!resp) {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(UpdateService.this, UpdateDialog.class);
                    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent1);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No updates Availaible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            volleyError.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
      }
}
```

Let me know if any more information is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ((MainActivity) mCon) is null, that's the issue

Comment: What do you mean by "presses rotates"? Is it the activity will change it orientation whenever you press the toolbar icon?

Comment: @HauLuu when icon is pressed then I have added a small refresh icon which rotates for some time and then executes updateservice and stops.

Answer (score 0):

My guess on the code line number and the error relate to rotate is:
most likely this line is causing null pointer

`MenuItem m = mymenu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);`

mymenu is null

when the screen is rotated, all ui views are recreated so old view will be gone, if async task took some time to execute and rotation happen in the middle of processing.
the right way to do is after task finish, find the latest current view object from the mainactivity first before doing any set,action,etc